# Error de permisos en carpeta Storage/app/public con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, linux, debian, permisos

Actualmente quiero almacenar temporalmente un archivo de excel para después enviarlo al e-mail, en localhost funciona correctamente y lo corro sobre Windows 10 de forma local, pero tengo un vps donde lo quiero montar, pero ahi me marca un error y es el siguiente:

```
The root path /var/www/html/AdminAppCatalogo/storage/app/public is not readable.
```

Esto pasa al querer guardar de forma temporal mi archivo esa ruta, ya pude los permisos `chmod 777 public/` cuando estoy en la carpeta app/, ademas de que tambien use `chmod 777 R public/` estando en la misma carpeta de app/

Comment: A qué usuario y grupo pertenecen ese archivo? Haz un ls -lisa y compara con el resto de archivos (tanto permisos como usuario:grupo a los que pertenecen)

Comment: me sale esto,  918569 4 drwxr-xr-x+ 2 root root 4096 Dec  2 05:24 public

Comment: Hazlo desde la carpeta storage

Comment: 395864 4 drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 Dec  2 05:24 app, ese fue el resultado desde la carpeta storage.

Comment: Tienes algún fichero que sí te deja ver desde el VPS? Tiene los mismos persimos?